# Trying to select from database specific column value using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database that I want to get a certain value from. I have a website where i'm allowing a user to create a new username based on their first name, last name, a selected username, and password. I have everything working except checking for duplicate usernames. I have tried the following code which only returns a 500 error.

```
    $userNameQuery = mysqli_query("Select * from Users where userName = $userName");
        if(!empty($usernameQuery){
            $userNameError = "Username exists, try again";
            $dontSubmit = true;
        }
```

I've been racking my brain over this for a couple of days now. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: What do you mean by 500 error? Did you check the (mysqli) error log? Possible mistake: Not using backticks ` in the query

Comment: FYI, you're missing some of these (') - that's an inverted comma, not a backtick!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [`mysqli_query()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) requires a DB connection object as the first parameter

Note, any time you run into 500 errors it generally means there is a syntax problem. you should turn on error reporting to log file in your php.ini so you can easily see what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have missed to close the bracket in `)` `if` condition

```
if(!empty($usernameQuery)){
```

instead of

```
if(!empty($usernameQuery){
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the help. :) Everything works now! :D

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. You have mispelt usernameQuery

   ```
   $userNameQuery = mysqli_query(...
       if(!empty($userNameQuery){
   ```
2. You missed a bracket

   ```
   if(!empty($userNameQuery)){
   ```
3. You need to have the backticks

   ```
   "Select * from Users where userName = `{$userName}`"
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate having some other eyes look at this. :) I just thought I would create this just for fun. lol